# pip install error

Tags: python, pip, launchpadlib

18.04.2 [pip install script as sudo was executed per instructions:](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/06/getting-started-with-the-nvidia-jetson-nano/)

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
rm get-pip.py
```

and an error (in bold below) was observed however the final `pip --version` seems to work correctly.

Is there any reason to be concerned regarding the error?  If so, what corrective action is needed?

> user@nanite:/$ sudo python3 get-pip.py WARNING: The directory
>   '/home/user/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by
>   the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the
>   permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,
>   you may want sudo's -H flag. WARNING: The directory
>   '/home/user/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the
>   current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the
>   permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo,
>   you may want sudo's -H flag. Collecting pip   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/e0/be401c003291b56efc55aeba6a80ab790d3d4cece2778288d65323009420/pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (1.4MB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 368kB/s  Collecting setuptools   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/51/f45cea425fd5cb0b0380f5b0f048ebc1da5b417e48d304838c02d6288a1e/setuptools-41.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>   (575kB)
>        |████████████████████████████████| 583kB 11.3MB/s  Collecting wheel   Downloading
>   https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/10/44230dd6bf3563b8f227dbf344c908d412ad2ff48066476672f3a72e174e/wheel-0.33.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> **ERROR: launchpadlib 1.10.6 requires test resources, which is not installed.**
>
> Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
>   Successfully installed pip-19.1.1 setuptools-41.0.1 wheel-0.33.4
>   user@nanite:/$ pip --version pip 19.1.1 from
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)

Answer (score 3):

You are installing `pip` with `sudo` but its using your user's home folder's python staging area. This can cause issues later on where paths added by the `sudo`'d process are not writable by non-`sudo`'d processes.

`sudo -H ...` will avoid those errors.

```
     -H, --set-home
                 Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory specified by the
                 target user's password database entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.
```

Would it not be preferable to install `pip3` via `apt`?

```
sudo apt install python3-pip -y && sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

This way any dependencies are met in accordance with the 18.04.2 LTS release.

Comment: Excellent post: the root cause is concisely summarized in the first sentence and the questions are addressed.  Please clarify why there is ']' character in the instruction and why it is preferable to install pip3 via apt?  I am a little surprised that the prescribed script does not meet dependencies

Comment: Sorry the `]` character was a holdover from a multiple-line block and was used to indicate a prompt you type things at. Regarding installing via `apt` it is less likely to have unresolved dependency issues. Using what is effectively a 3rd party (to canonical) script relies on that group knowing exactly how your system is configured... which does not seem to have worked out in the case of get-pip.py.